# How to capture output from tcpdump

Tags: command-line

I'd like to capture the output from tcpdump and use it as input for a second command. By the way I don't want to use the pcap format!

I tried

```
sudo tcpdump -q ip > ./out.txt
```

When I watched the file I saw the whole STDOUT was written  to the file all the time but I expected the file to be overwritten with the new content only. Is all the STDOUT buffered or cleared when written to the terminal?

- Is there a way I can read only the partial updates from STDOUT?
- How can I redirect output continuously from tcpdump to an other cmd?

Does this work ?

```
sudo tcpdump -q ip | my_command
```

Comment: If I understand correctly you want only the last N line to be written to the file, is this correct?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To always overwrite the file with each new `tcpdump` line:

```
sudo tcpdump -l -q ip | awk '{system("echo " $0 " > out")}'
```

---

To use the output for an other comand, eg `awk`

- `$3` = only the 3rd column

  ```
  sudo tcpdump -l -q ip | awk '{print $3}'
  ```
- Filter by `tcp`

  ```
  sudo tcpdump -l -q ip | awk '/tcp/ {print $0}'
  ```
- Or a combination:

  ```
  sudo tcpdump -l -q ip | awk '/tcp/ {"echo " $0 " > out"}'
  ```

---

from `man tcpdump`

```
   -l     Make  stdout  line  buffered.
          Useful if you want to see the data while capturing it.
          E.g.,
                 tcpdump -l | tee dat
          or
                 tcpdump -l > dat & tail -f dat
```

Comment: Gets the content replaced everytime tcpdump writes to STDOUT ? In terms of replaced i dont mean multiple calls to tcpdump rather the contionous output the command generates!

Comment: Now yes =) `sudo tcpdump -l -q ip | awk '{system("echo "$0" > out")}'`